# Erro ao converter data php

Tags: php, data

Estou recebendo a seguinte data de um formulário: `26/09/2016`  preciso converte-la para: `2016-09-01` estou usando o seguinte comando:     `$v_data= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data));` só que esta dando o seguinte retorno: `1970-01-01`, o que estaria errado ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você está recebendo a data do mysql e quer converter para o formato brasileiro use o seguinte comando:

```
$data = implode("/", array_reverse(explode("-", $data)));
```

Isto vai criar a data do mysql em formato brasileiro.

Se você quer preparar a data em formato brasileiro para inserir no mysql use:

```
$data = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $data)));
```

Comment: Utilizado: $data = implode(“-“,array_reverse(explode(“/”,$data))); , Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Como seria a mesma situação para moeda ?

Comment: $numero = 1234.56;
echo number_format($numero, 2, ',', '.');

Comment: Na verdade e minha soma que esta dando errado,vou postar uma nova pergunta ...

Comment: Segue a pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155079/erro-ao-somar-2-valores-em-php

Answer (score 2):

Tive problema parecido, resolvi assim:

```
$data = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', $data)));
```

Answer (score 2):

para utilizar o strtotime da maneira que você colocou, basta substituir as "/" por "-".

```
$v_data= date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $data)))
```

que dará certo!