# Erro ao somar 2 valores em php

Tags: php, matemática

Tenho esse valor: `250,59`  e esse outro valor: `20,19` quando somo os dois,não esta calculando os centavos e retorna: `270`

Segue meu calculo:

```
$mo = $vl_mobra ; //VALOR 1 250,59
$mt = $vl_mat;    //VALOR 2 20,19
$vt = $mo + $mt;  //SOMA
```

Veja mais exemplos:

```
20.000,66  //VALOR 1
10.000,99  //VALOR 2
30         // TOTAL

500,99    //VALOR 1
100,88    //VALOR 2
600       //TOTAL

function moedaPhp($str_num){
    $vt = str_replace('.', '', $str_num);
    $vt = str_replace(',', '.', $vt);
    return $vt;
}

echo moedaPhp($vt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta é uma pergunta repetida.

Os decimais em PHP são separados por `.` (ponto) e não há separadores de milhares.

```
<?php
function moedaPhp($str_num){
    $resultado = str_replace('.', '', $str_num); // remove o ponto
    $resultado = str_replace(',', '.', $resultado); // substitui a vírgula por ponto
    return floatval($resultado); // transforma a saída em FLOAT
}

$mo = $vl_mobra ; //VALOR 1 250,59
$mt = $vl_mat;    //VALOR 2 20,19
$vt = moedaPhp($mo) + moedaPhp($mt);  //SOMA
echo $vt; // retorna: 270.78
```

Veja minha resposta em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152534/31016

Comment: eu coloquei sua função,mais retornou da mesma forma,editei a pergunta com a função,veja se fiz errado.

Comment: Veja o exemplo atualizado, faltou o floatval na função.

Comment: Perfeito,Obrigado !

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado!

Answer (score 2):

Utilize ponto para os decimais e não separe os milhares.

```
$vl_mobra = 1250.59;
$vl_mat = 2020.19;

$mo = $vl_mobra ; //VALOR 1 250,59
$mt = $vl_mat;    //VALOR 2 20,19
$vt = $mo + $mt;  //SOMA

echo $vt;
```